# Wordpress classic text editor not displaying post content and toolbar is missing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-5

I am using wordpress 5 along with Classic Editor plugin. But I am not able to edit posts using it. The post edit area is completely blank and the toolbar above it also not showing

[image: it].

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: are you sure the content isn't specified on a page template? there is a setting where you can hide/show the toolbar at the top of the content editor..

Comment: try to update your post_max_size , memory_limit , upload_max_size , max_execution_time . May be it will help

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the mixed-content error. The js file of the wordpress classic editor plugin was not loading because it was using http protocol on an https site. So I fixed it by adding this line in wp-config file.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

It will force all the content to be served over https and fix the mixed-content error.

Comment: After 2 hours of looking into different solutions, this saved my life! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. What I did was to downgrade my WordPress version to a previous version. And now, it's working fully.

Answer (score 0):

This situation presented itself yesterday, July 27, 2021.  I called Siteground, my host, and they restored a backup from a week earlier.  That didn't work and I was out $30.  I switched themes with no success.  Long story short, I deactivated my 13 plugins and brought them up one by one.  I noted a 'Siteground Security' plugin released yesterday, July 27, 2021 when the issue presented itself.  As I brought back my plugins, the text editor appeared UNTIL I activated the 'Siteground Security' plugin; then the text editor disappeared.  I am NOT tech-savvy, but this worked for me.